# Commenting on off-topic questions

Tags: discussion

When marking a question off-topic, may I recommend that you politely direct the OP to the correct stack exchange?   Saying something like

> Home networking is off topic here.  You can ask this on Superuser.

will help them get the answer they're looking for.

Without a comment, I'm sure the OP has no clue what's wrong, and it gives a cold, unwelcoming feel to this SE, IMO.

Comment: Even better, consider defining site-specific off-topic close reasons for things like this. Look to [sf] for what might be some relevant examples.

Comment: That's OK too, as long as we give some suggestion where the proper place for the question is.

Comment: My understanding, is that some of the more specific off-topic close reasons and migration options become available to us as we graduate beta.